# Javascript - replace string basing on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I've got

`mystring =  "Google"` and I've got array

`myarray = ["o", "o", "e"]`

I want to do something like

```
mystring.replace(myarray, "<b>$</b>")
```

So it would return `G<b>o</b><b>o</b>gl<b>e</b>`  - every comming matching letter from array is wrapped in  tag.

I also have proper regexp for it `/.*?(o).*?(o).*(e).*/i` That have matching groups for o followed by o followed by e.

Those arrays and strings are auto generated (fuzzy search) so I'm not able to say how big array and strings will be. I only know the letters to look in the string.

Comment: The match would be for only the first ocurrency of each element of the array? I ask because you don't need two `o` in your array if not.

Comment: I need to have two o in array as it says me I need to 'bold' two o's in string not only one. And also I need to respect order of letters in array. So first o means 'find firs o in string' and then 'find another o but it has to be after last match from array'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
mystring =  "Google";
myarray = ["o", "o", "e"];

var r = mystring.replace(new RegExp( '(' + myarray.join('|') + ')', 'g'), "<b>$1</b>");
//=> G<b>o</b><b>o</b>gl<b>e</b>
```

**EDIT:** Based on discussions below:

```
mystring =  "Google";
myarray = ["g", "o", "e"];

var r = mystring;
for (var i in myarray) {
    r = r.replace(new RegExp('('+myarray[i]+')(?!<\\/b>)', "i"), "<b>$1</b>");
}
console.log(r); // <b>G</b><b>o</b>ogl<b>e</b>
```

**PS:** Due to use of **negative lookahead** `(?!<\/b>)` same letter is not replaced twice.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fTM8/5/)

Comment: Lets say array would be ["g", "o", "e"] - then what should happen is:  g, first o (only the first, not every) after found g and firs e after found o should be 'bolded'. btw. I'm not the one who voted down.

Comment: 1+ It is exactly what I did at fiddle. I would like to know what is wrong too.

Comment: Can you supply fiddle? here is mine : http://jsfiddle.net/8fTM8/ (two o's bolded, should be only the first after g). Same with g's - only the first in order should be bolded

Comment: Here's mine http://jsfiddle.net/8fTM8/ - expected result, first G, first o after last match, first e after last match to be bold. Actual result - every g, o, e bolded.

Comment: For the case you supply on previous comment it wont work. So the algorithm for this would be to store the replaces that was maded so you wont replace the same string again. And a little worst, if the chars on the array are out of order with the word it has to be a little more complicated.

Comment: Actualy my goal is to bold matching letter during fuzzy search like in sublime text etc. So input could be "ge" against "Google" string and result should be G and e bolded in string. Maybe I'm going wrong way here?

Comment: For the last comment of the OP still wont work. You have to add ignorecase `RegExp('('+myarray[i]+')','i')`

Comment: Actually i've found another flaw. If you provide `"o","o","e"` your fiddle would change only the first o and as the OP asked it has to change two of then. The final result would be `<b><b>o</b></b>`

Comment: The solution would be a negative lookbehind `(?<!>)(o)`, but as javascript would not support this, I don't know how to solve it either.

Comment: @Kluska000: My updated code works with this case, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8fTM8/4/

Comment: @JorgeCampos: See my updated code to avoid `<b><b>o</b></b>` for your test case.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos for your helpful comments to make me arrive at the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to go:

```
var tmp = mystring;
for (l in myarray) {
    tmp = tmp.replace(new RegExp('('+myarray[l]+'(?:\\B|$))'), '<b>$1</b>');
}
```

**Console:**

```
G<b>o</b><b>o</b>gl<b>e</b>
```

The `(?:\\B|$)` makes the regex not producing `G<b><b>o</b></b>ogl<b>e</b>`

You could also use:

```
new RegExp('('+myarray[l]+'(?!<))')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with something like this:

```
var boldByArray = function( string, array ){
    var result = [];
    string.split('').forEach( function( letter ){
        if( array.indexOf( letter ) == 0 ){
             result.push( '<b>' + array.shift() +'</b>' );
        }
        else {    
            result.push( letter );
         }
    });
    return result.join('');
}
```

The result for array `boldByArray('google', ['e','g','o'])` will be `Googl<b>e</b>` because you want to respect the order, so it finds the `e`, then looks for `g` and `o` after that `e` which never comes. `boldByArray('google', ['x','g','o'])` will be just `google`, because there's no `x`.

**http://jsfiddle.net/wuSaE/1/**

Updated with fuzzy matching demo gathered from comments you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/wuSaE/3/